# Is this an example of recursion in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, variables, recursion

I'm currently a bit befuddled... I'm tasked with finding the value of x, is this an example of recursion? I am not asking for a straight answer for the value of x, I can find that out with some guidance from the Overflow community. I get confused at a = b, and b = t, then where is says return the function.

Any and all help is greatly appreciated!

```
function f(a, b, c) {
  if (c > 1) {
    c = c - 1;
    var t = a + b;
    a = b;
    b = t;
    return f(a, b, c);
  }
  return a + b;
}
var x = f(1, 3, 4);
```

Comment: function `f` calls function `f` ... that's recursion

Comment: If variables had meaningful names the code would have been easier to follow.

Comment: *I get confused at* ... what's the confusion? `a = b`, assigns a to the current value of b, `b = t` assigns b to the value of t which is the original a + b  - you could rewrite the code from `c = c - 1` to `return f(a, b, c)` as simply `return f(b, a+b, c -1)`

Comment: Yes it calling the same function f inside the f function with new values of a,b,c - its a recursion

Comment: This is a bad example of recursion since you usually don't need local variables (`t`) or reassign arguments locally (e.g. `a = b`). Try to achieve the same computation solely with arguments and without reassignments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this line here: `return f(a, b, c)` - this is recursion as it is calling itself at the end. It's modifying the parameters that it receives and re-calling itself again.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is an example of recursion. You can tell this because function `f()` calls function `f()` (itself) with a smaller subset on line 7.

You might find [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/scripting/javascript/advanced/recursion-javascript) from Microsoft helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, `f` invokes itself, so that's all that's needed for recursion.

Additionally, it's a tail recursion that can be optimized by the engine to avoid the call stack from growing too large. This is because the recursive call has no need to maintain the current variable scope after its call. All variables that are used are used in the argument position, and not after the call returns, so the current stack frame could be reused on the next call.

Not too many engines right now optimize for proper tail calls, but it was added as a requirement of ECMAScript 2015, so they should get there eventually.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, its recursion, the line  return f(a, b, c); is been called again inside the f function with new values of a,b,c